# I can get correct data to display in my ERB, but I'm not following the standards. Can you help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, coding-style, erb

I have two models: user and transaction. Transactions table has user_id column for storing the id of the user responsible for transaction.

On the index.html.erb for transactions this was the auto generated code:

```
<td><%=h transaction.user_id %></td>
```

Since I want user's name to be displayed, in my first approach I converted this to:

```
# Index.html.erb
# First approach
<td><%=h User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id =?", transaction.user_id]).firstname %></td>
```

This got me the firstname correctly, but I was not sure this was the right way so I created this method in user.rb (model file):

```
# user.rb
# Second approach
def find_by_id id
    @firstname = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id =?", id]).firstname
    return @firstname
end
```

And modified the line in index.html.erb to:

```
# Index.html.erb
# Second approach
<td><%=h User.find_by_id(transaction.user_id) %></td>
```

But this does not give me user's firstname and instead the output is something like *#`<User:0x000000021ecf60>`*

I am not sure: a) Why this is happening and how to get the return from method to print correctly & b) If I am following standards even in second approach to getting the username printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your association between transactions and users setup properly in the transaction model:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you can simply do:

```
<td><%=h transaction.user.firstname %></td>
```

The reason your 'find_by_id' method didn't work is because you created it as an instance method. So, when you called `User.find_by_id`, it used the normal Rails 'magic method' (not so magic at all - it just uses `method_missing`) for finding records. I would argue that it is very bad design to override this method to just return the first name of the user when you've got all this object-oriented loveliness around.

Comment: I had belongs_to and has_many associations set correctly. I did not know how to use their power. I've recently started coding after a long time and it is mostly learning by discovery for me.

Comment: I came across **Agile web development with Rails**. Is there some better resource you can refer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably forgot to insert `belongs_to` association to transaction.rb model.

Be sure that table transaction has a field `user_id`.

More on this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks! I had the associations but did not know I can use them like this! :)